# How to iterate a comma delimited string using Loop in Microsoft Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework

I have a comman delimited string of ids which I would like to iterate over using a Loop in Microsoft Bot Framework Composer.

I am using Split to create a new array using the following.

```
${split(turn.activity.value.people, ',')}
```

This outputs the following:

```
{
"lgType": "Activity",
"text": [
"97d76b2-4be8-4571-bc35-1e2d61ee",
"0e51155-e277-4b51-bad0-750db266"
]
}
```

How can I setup a Loop for each item?

I am getting the following error when I try an loop through the results of the split.

```
Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-control-conversation-flow?tabs=v2x
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#split